# How to use my Arch Linux machine to access my Raspberry Pi, which is on the local network?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have Raspbian installed on my Raspberry Pi Zero, which is connected to my internet modem by Ethernet cable.

My Arch Linux desktop computer also is connected to my modem via Ethernet cable.

How do I access my Pi Zero from my Arch Linux PC?

Answer (score 0):

You use SSH. I don't remember the default setup, you probably will have to change it anyway. But that's the cleanest way, I think.

Just change the network settings on your pi to use your local network IP address (such as 10.0.0.3 or 192.168.3.3, whatever you're using).

The Pi should already have the SSH server installed. If not, just install it.